# How to access Microsoft Exchange mails using OWA(Outlook Web Access)

Tags: ios, objective-c, exchange-server, outlook-web-app

As I am new to Microsoft Exchange and OWA please help me.

My goal is to create a sample program/application on iPhone/iPad (iOS) through which I can access Exchange mails. (Exchange 2003, 2007, 2010, 2013)

I am aware about EWS and EAS. 
It would be helpful if you advise any other possible way to access exchange mails.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I've spend many hours on that subject, one (working) thing I've found is this:
https://github.com/jgallen23/OWAParser

My problem was, after testing many times with my company's Exchange server they've locked my account. And even thought it works, after changing something small in the server configuration it will stop working, and that wasn't an option for me.

Hope this helps you! :-)